# I need to know why? and If I change this line to "println(name+two)" error solved?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
    val two=2
    val name:String?
    name="Mensh"
    println(two+name)
}
```

This is a simple kotlin app and I got the error on `println(two+name)`:

```
Error:(8, 16) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public final operator fun plus(other: Byte): Int defined in kotlin.Int 
public final operator fun plus(other: Double): Double defined in kotlin.Int 
public final operator fun plus(other: Float): Float defined in kotlin.Int 
public final operator fun plus(other: Int): Int defined in kotlin.Int 
public final operator fun plus(other: Long): Long defined in kotlin.Int 
public final operator fun plus(other: Short): Int defined in kotlin.Int
```

Comment: Maybe you can format your question nicely so that I'm able to understand what you want? As it stands now, it looks like a wall of error message here. If that is already the exact way how Kotlin prints the error message, then you should probably drop that and try JQuery instead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't compile in Kotlin is because there is no implicit conversion of a numeric to a String when concatenating, unlike in Java.

For example, this would compile:

```
fun main(args:Array<String>) { 
    val two = 2
    val name = "Mensh"
    println(two.toString() + name) 
}
```

As others have mentioned, string templates would be a more idiomatic way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are giving you the solution, but are not explaining your error.

```
Error:(8, 16) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public final operator fun plus(other: Byte): Int defined in kotlin.Int 
public final operator fun plus(other: Double): Double defined in kotlin.Int 
public final operator fun plus(other: Float): Float defined in kotlin.Int 
public final operator fun plus(other: Int): Int defined in kotlin.Int 
public final operator fun plus(other: Long): Long defined in kotlin.Int 
public final operator fun plus(other: Short): Int defined in kotlin.Int
```

Kotlin has [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) for `+` operator.

`println(two+name)`: Here the compiler tries to use the plus operator overloaded function of `Int` which has a `String` paramter, but there are no such function. Hence you get the above error. You can see all the plus operator overloaded function in the error above.

`println(name+two)`: But `String` has a plus operator overloaded function which accepts `Any?` parameter. So you are not getting any error. This is the plus operator overloaded function of String:

```
public operator fun plus(other: Any?): String
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin has its own style of formatting Strings, try:

```
println("$two$name")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, you can concatenate using [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#using-string-templates):

```
val c = "$two $name"
print(c)
```

Other [info here.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates)